# Golang, will context.TODO ever give error

Tags: go, go-context

```
ctx = context.TODO()
cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, <some_cmd>, <some_arg>)
fmt.Println(ctx.Err())
```

Is ctx.Err() is ever going to non-nil with ctx being context.TODO()?

Comment: No. (Too short for an answer.)

Comment: Only if you wrap it with  `WithCancel` or `WithTimeout/WithDeadline`. `context.TODO()` is just an empty context, identical  to `context.Background()`. It does nothing on its own. Its name `TODO` is just a reminder: you are unsure which context to  use, and plan to come  back later to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

context.TODO().Err() will always return nil, as can be easily seen in [the source code](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.2:src/context/context.go;l=169-218;drc=bd6cd7db07f314443acdb980393f57386d40551f):

```
package context

// An emptyCtx is never canceled, has no values, and has no deadline.
type emptyCtx int

func (*emptyCtx) Err() error {
    return nil
}

// ...

var (
    todo       = new(emptyCtx)
)

// ...

// TODO returns a non-nil, empty Context. Code should use context.TODO when
// it's unclear which Context to use or it is not yet available (because the
// surrounding function has not yet been extended to accept a Context
// parameter).
func TODO() Context {
    return todo
}
```